# Перенос программы на другую платформу

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net

Имеется программа на C#(.NET) можно ли как-то безболезненно и с минимальными затратами времени перенести её на linux? Или же надо всё-таки начинать её переписывать на кросплатформенных языках? Спасибо.

Comment: Mono уже не устроил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть не в языке, суть в используемых библиотках. C# как язык кросс-платформенен. Со следующей версии будет кросс-платформенен ещё более: .NET из коробки будет поддерживать несколько осей, не требуя отдельного Mono.

Если вы используете только консоль, то с большой вероятностью программа на C#, запущенная на Mono, просто будет работать.

Если вы используете WinForms без сторонних библиотек, то программа, скорее всего, запустится, но выглядеть будет не очень. Если используете прямые вызовы к WinAPI, то программа упадёт при попытке ими воспользоваться. Чтобы выглядеть солиднее, вы можете захотеть переписать GUI под конкретные оси (эта идея продвигается(-лась?) мелкомягкими даже для приложений под разные виндовые платформы).

Если вы используете WPF или ещё какие-либо библиотеки-фреймворки, которые не были портированы и для которых нет аналогов, то вам придётся переписывать некоторые слои приложения. Если у вас бизнес-логика хорошо отделена от представления, то нужно будет переписать только GUI. Если в коде лапша из всех слоёв, то переписывание превратится в мучение.

Аналогично для случая, когда используются сторонние, а не встроенные библиотеки или фреймворки: вы будете зависеть от того, доступны ли они для Mono, и насколько кросс-платформенно они написаны.

Comment: Использую консоль, что касается библиотек использую только system и дочерние

Comment: @НиколаКривошея System — понятие широкое. :) Многое непортированное (или криво портированное) тоже там находится. Впрочем, если у вас консоль и никаких хитрых заумных технологий, то с большой долей вероятности достаточно будет просто перекомпилировать.

Comment: отправка post и get запросов на сайты и обработка данных

Comment: @НиколаКривошея Должно нормально заработать. Веб-часть нормально портирована. Более того, это одна из самых активных кросс-платформенных областей на шарпе.